# Laravel make model with migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I'm creating a model on the Laravel 5 with this command:

```
php artisan make:model Settings
```

As it shows on the video lessons that as soon as model is created, new migration file also must be created. But, in my situtation, migration is not being created. 
How can I get the migration generated when model is created?

composer.json:

```
...
    "require": {
            "php": ">=5.5.9",
            "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
        },
...
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I'm guessing your build of L5 is fairly old, as they disabled creating migrations alongside the model creation.

Try running the ff:

```
php artisan make:model Settings --migration
```

Comment: I just yesterday installed the Laravel by using composer, how come it can be old?

Comment: Can you paste your composer.json?

Comment: Laravel version is 5.1.8. you were right, I used --migraiton and it worked. Posted composer.json

Comment: careful with laravel name convention. models are singular.

Answer (score 64):

Try using this Command

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -m
```

OR

```
php artisan make:model ModelName --migration
```

It will create model with migration class

Comment: It's a little bit of an aside, but there should not be an underscore between Model and Name in terms of conventions.  Just making that note since this seems like a question that many beginners would flock to.

Comment: @helios456 i put Underscore because people can understand where to put Name of Model Read in side of Bracket [ Model_Name = Name of the model user want he can put anything at the position].

Comment: Updated and removed the underscore so it won't mislead those who didn't read comment

Answer (score 29):

Also you can use this command:

```
    php artisan make:model ModelName -m
```

and if you wanna make controller for your model, you should write this command :

```
   php artisan make:model ModelName -mc
   
   // or 

   php artisan make:model ModelName -mcr  //(r: for resource methods)
```

Answer (score 21):

2020 update:

You can now do:

```
php artisan make:model ModelName -a
```

To create a:

1. model
2. controller
3. seeder
4. migration
5. factory

All using one command.

Answer (score 19):

Create **Model** and **Migration** :

`php artisan make:model Image -m`

Create **Model**, **Migration** and **Controller** with **resource** :

`php artisan make:model Image -mcr`

Shortcut to generate a **model**, **migration**, **factory**, **seeder**, **policy**, **controller**, and form **requests** :

`php artisan make:model Image --all`

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `make:model` flags like;

`php artisan make:model Setting -m`

[image]

Help: **`php artisan make:model --help`**

Answer (score 1):

It's weird because to **skip** migration you could use the flag `--no-migration`. That means that calling `php artisan make:model Foo` should automatically create everything. Does artisan show any errors? Did you check logs? What Laravel version are you using? 5? 5.1?

Comment: it is latest version, I just yesterday installed and started learning Laravel. Looked at Logs file in storage/logs no any error is showing. Artisan is completing successfully, not showing any error too.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to generate a database migration when you generate the model, you may use the --migration or -m option

php artisan make:model Settings --migration

php artisan make:model Settings -m